# MVC Generating DropDownLists Dynamically

Tags: model-view-controller, drop-down-menu

Here is my ViewModel,

public class FormGroupsAssociationViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {

```
    public FormGroupsAssociationViewModel()
    {
        FormTypeFormGroupViewModels = new List<FormTypeFormGroupViewModel>();
    }

    public FormGroupsAssociationViewModel(IList<FormTypeFormGroupViewModel> formTypeFormGroupViewModels)
    {
        this.FormTypeFormGroupViewModels = formTypeFormGroupViewModels;

    }

    public IList<FormTypeFormGroupViewModel> FormTypeFormGroupViewModels { get; set; }

}
```

public class FormTypeFormGroupViewModel
    {

```
    public FormTypeFormGroupViewModel()
    {

    }

    public FormTypeFormGroupViewModel(FormType formType, IEnumerable<FormGroup> formGroups)
    {
        this.FormTypeId = formType.FormTypeID;
        this.Title = formType.Title;
        this.FormGroups = new SelectList(formGroups, "FormGroupId", "Title",  "3");
    }

    public int FormTypeId;
    public string Title;
    public SelectList FormGroups;
    public int SelectedFormGroup;

}
```

and heres the view:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.FormTypeFormGroupViewModels.Count; i++)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Model.FormTypeFormGroupViewModels[i].Title
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => Model.FormTypeFormGroupViewModels[i].SelectedFormGroup, Model.FormTypeFormGroupViewModels[i].FormGroups)
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
```

and finally the controller is:

```
[HttpPost]
    [UnitOfWork]
    public String Associations(FormGroupsAssociationViewModel model)
    {

        String s = string.Empty;

        foreach (var formTypeFormGroupViewModel in model.FormTypeFormGroupViewModels)
        {
            s = s + formTypeFormGroupViewModel.SelectedFormGroup.ToString();
        }

        return s;

    }
```

The problem i've got is the SelectedFormGroup is returning 0 rather than the actual selectedValue. If anyone has any ideas they would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers

Gareth

Answer (score 0):

Solved this,

In my ViewModel, the SelectedFormGroup was declared like this:

```
public int SelectedFormGroup;
```

This needed to be changed to:

```
public int SelectedFormGroup{get; set;}
```